# instant win procedure in PHP / MySQL - how to make sure only one winner is chosen?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building an instant win action for a competition draw. Basically at a given randomly selected minute of an hour, the next user to submit their details should be chosen as the winner.

The problem I'm having is that if MySQL is running multiple connections, then how do I stop two or three winners being drawn by mistake? Can I limit the connections, or maybe get PHP to wait until all current MySQL connections are closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look at lock tables

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: This looks interesting! If I lock a table and the script dies for some reason, will the table remain locked, or will the end of a mysql connection also unlock all tables again?

Comment: Thanks this is perfect. Love learning about things like this :)

Comment: If the connection for a client session terminates, whether normally or abnormally, the server implicitly releases all table locks held by the session (transactional and nontransactional). You will need to be careful that you don't run a long process while tables are locked, as depending on the lock type it will block access to other queries

Comment: I think what was causing the problem was that I was sending the winner an email before saving the entry flagged as winner=true. That gave other connections enough time to get in there and be selected as well. Lock tables worked perfect thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the starting value of a field that you're updating as the concurrency check in your WHERE clause when you make the update. That way, only the 1st one to be executed will go through, because after that it will no longer match the WHERE clause. You can tell whose went through using the `mysql_affected_rows()` function, which will return `1` for the successful update and `0` for any others.

Comment: Hi there, I think I understand you, but could you write up a quick bit of SQL to show me, just to make sure?

Comment: Do we really want to be promoting use of the mysql_* library?

Answer (score 0):

Use a timestamp field "registertime" in the user details table. When inserting the data, use the NOW() function to insert into the registertime field.

When you choose a random minute, convert that to a unix time.

The winner is: SELECT * FROM userTable WHERE registertime > -- the timestamp of your random minute -- ORDER BY registertime LIMIT 1

Comment: Hi there, 

This is what I'm doing, but I need to show the user that they are the winner as soon as they submit their form, so if I have 2 concurrent connections, they both will see a winner message, which I want to avoid.

Comment: Maybe you could use microtime() to get the milliseconds, instead of NOW().

Comment: If you have a query that returns only the first entry after the target time, I don't think concurrent sessions are a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a small status table somewhere that records the hour of the previous draw. If the new record's insert time is at a different hour, do the check if they're a winner.

If they are, you update the status table with this new "Winners" draw hour, and that'll prevent any more draws being made for the rest of the hour. Though, what happens if, by chance, no one actually "wins" the draw in any particular hour? Do you guarantee a win to the last person who registered, or there just isn't a winner at all?